# getting out values from string format c#

Tags: c#, string.format

I have this line of code

`merchant = string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);`
what is the correct way to get values out of the variable using `.` notation?
Is there a way from this to do that?

Comment: More context would be helpful. Why do you need to get them out? It would be much simpler just not to put them in.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean. You've *got* the two parts already... If you've *only* got the output, then you've got to face the problem of FirstName="A B" LastName="C" vs FirstName="A" LastName="B C"

Comment: You want to get substrings out of strings? 
            string s = "aaa";
            s.Substring(0, 1); something like this?

Comment: do you mean new line between them? use `\n` between {0} to {1}

Comment: You have already a `Person` instance, so you can use `.`-notation: `string firstName = person.FirstName;`.

Comment: i have context where i pull them out from model and after that i want to use the first name and last name seperatly

Comment: yup. you already have Person instance with you..why you need to split merchant string to do that

Comment: because i do not want to give the `person` further then this  
`person` contains more then just first name and last name

Comment: @user37202: why don't you _work_ with the `Person` instance until you're going to diplay something like the full-name? It's  almost impossible to separate the first- and lastname from a string because you don't know where the firstname ends (it can contain spaces too).

Comment: Create list of firstname and lastname and initialize that list here. you dont have to take person further than. just use that list

Comment: Tim is right - thank you!
now I feel sorry for coming here to ask this :D ** happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Merchent a type first so you can access the properties of its object with "." notation.

```
public class Merchant
{
public string Firstname {get;set;}
public string Lastname {get;set;}
// any other properties of merchant
}
```

Then you can access it in the main class like this .

```
Merchant m = new Merchant(){ Firstname=person.FirstName, Lastname= person.Lastname };
string a = m.Firstname;
string b = m.Lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of serialization and you just need to parse the result string later, then the following code can help you:

```
merchant = string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName); 
var result = merchant.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// this ^ won't work if firstName or lastName contain spaces, so you can use another separator:
merchant = string.Format("{0}#{1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName); 
var result = merchant.Split("#", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var firstName = result[0];
var lastName = result[1];
```

But it is not an object, it is just a string.

Comment: This won't work if initial strings contain spaces.

Comment: Hmm.. Usually first and last names don't contain spaces, but you are right, there may be problems, if, for example, the middle name also included in the firstName string.

Comment: Jean-Claude Van Damme would not approve @ZuoLi ;)

Comment: yes, i've updated the answer for him personally :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing is merging two separate strings into one new string. There is no way of getting back the initial strings from the result string without beforehand knowing the exact length of the input strings (in which case you would be able to use String.Substring).